# What Is the Keyboard Shortcut for Moving to Last Message in Mac OS X Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-mail

I'm on Mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard).

In Mail, I have the first message in my Inbox selected and I'm trying to navigate to the last message using my keyboard.

In Thunderbird, I just hit the End key, which for me is "Function-right arrow" because I'm on a MacBook Pro.

In Mail, with the first message selected, if I hit "Function-right arrow" (i.e. End), the scroll bar moves down, allowing me to see the messages at the bottom of the list, but the first message at the top of the list is still selected. What I want is for the last message to be selected.

I've tried lots of key combinations and searched for the answer but haven't been able to find it.  Please help.  I posted this originally at [discussions.apple.com](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9156234#9156234) but the only advice I received was to file a bug with Apple, which I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>down arrow</kbd> and keep it pressed for > 1s. The same goes for going to the top of the mail list, but type <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>up arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect answer!  Thank you so much!  This really belongs in the app's "Mail keyboard shortcuts" help page.

Comment: Props to Efge:
http://www.hawkwings.net/2006/10/03/moving-around-mailapp-using-the-keyboard/#comment-94083

Comment: ⌥↑ and ⌥↓ stopped working in 10.7. (They no longer work on iTunes playlists either.)

Comment: I had the same question for Outlook 2011.  This worked!

Answer (score 13):

- OS X Lion:  <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>
- OS X Mavericks: <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: fn-→ shows the last message, but focus stays on the original message. How do you open the last message or navigate from it with the keyboard?