# How can I select first/last message in Mail.app in Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-mail, osx-mountain-lion

The closest I got was to use an Applescript service that was given as a tip for Lion (see: [What is the Keyboard Shortcut for Moving to the First/Last Message in Mail.app in Mac OS X Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/342898)):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Mail" to set selected messages of first message viewer to last item of messages of first message viewer
end run
```

However, this script doesn't work if the last message is a thread with multiple messages.

Comment: You can change the layout to be without the threaded conversations in preferences>Viewing(tab)>Use Classic Layout. Or by Mailbox, under the View menu. Of course this is not an ideal workaround if you really need/want threads as well.